# How to manipulate elements on the Insert Media Attachment settings popup

Tags: jquery, media-library

Is there anyway to show/hide elements in the attachment display settings popup window using jquery?
for example, if I wanted to hide this div:
[image: attachment display settings]

I would think I could hide it like this.
    $('.attachment-display-settings').hide();
on a file included on the WordPress admin screen(using the admin_enqueue_scripts hook). But that doesn't work. It only seems to work on the main admin screen, but not on any of the popups. Can anyone help out here?

[image]

Comment: Because by the time the pop up is created your jquery hide command has already happened, it's closing the barn doors when the horse has already bolted. Perhaps you'd have more luck with CSS. Can you update your question with some context for why you're trying to do this?

Comment: Yeah, I only used this example for simplicity purposes. I made some additions to the media attachment window using the 'attachment_fields_to_edit' hook. But I need to establish some interaction between the fields. For example. I need to hide/show certain fields based on an option picked in a select menu. Is there any way to do this? Thanks for the quick response Tom.

Comment: Also are you referring to this screen when editing an image inside a post, or when it's in the media library? It might look like they're the same screen but they aren't, and edit different things than you'd expect

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for running javascript on that screen though, can you not using the existing JS used to add those fields to that screen?

Comment: Editing an image while inside a post for now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but the second comment. You're saying I would use js instead of the `attachment_fields_to_edit' hook? Ideally I want to use use  `attachment_fields_to_edit' and be able to interact with those fields using jquery, if that is possible.

Comment: oooh, so if you're in post content and click on an image and bring up the edit screen, you're not editing the attachment, you're editing the image in the post. Hence trying to do things like pull in post meta from the attachment make no sense. It's also why changing the title etc doesn't modify the original attachment. Unfortunately, this screen is near identical to the one in the media library which actually edits an attachment, leading to confusion. Unless you're talking about the edit screen when you have the media library insert dialog open? Be very clear and precise else you'll confuse

Comment: Sorry. I am adding a post and clicking the "Add Media" button. Then I select an image in the Media Library. The fields i want to interact with each other show up on the right after I select the image.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2aLh.png

Comment: Does that clear things up for you Tom?